# changing background color in loop it executes after loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change background color in switch loop, so it should change color before execute alert. But changing background color after close alert window. Could not figure out why, any one can help?

```
var colors = ["blue", "orange" , "red" , "yellow"];
var array_lenght = colors.length;
var random_color;
var guessed_color;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;

function do_game() {    

    var random_number = Math.random() * 4;
    var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
    random_color = colors[random_number_integer];

    while (!finished) {
        guesses +=1;
        guessed_color = prompt ("blue, orange, red, yellow\n\nWhich one am i thinking?");       
        finished = check_guess();       
    }   
}

function check_guess() {    

    var n = guessed_color.localeCompare(random_color);
    var existence = colors.lastIndexOf(guessed_color);

    if (existence >= 0) {

        switch (n) {

        case 0:
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = guessed_color;
        alert ("You found it!\n\n" + "It took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game");
        return true;
        break;

        case -1:
        alert ("Your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
        break;

        case  1:
        alert ("Your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
        break;

        }
    }
    else 
        alert ("Please type a color from the list.");

}
```

Comment: Just saying, you're storing the return value of `check_guess()` into `finished` but you don't return anything

Comment: Be aware that `alert` (and other modal popups) will in some browsers remove some saturation from a colored background, to give it a *"disabled"* kind of look. The true background color is restored once the modal dialog is closed. Even a white background becomes grey when a popup is opened.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean @AndrewL. ın case 0, ıt changes the value of fınıshed to true that means stop while loop. So what is wrong in there?

Comment: Well, you're storing the return value of `check_guess()` into `finished` but in 3 cases (2 switch, 1 if) you don't return anything so it has the change of being undefined

Comment: I think if i do not return anything, it will keep its current value, am i wrong? I'm just asking :) Should we return a value all the time even if we do not change the value?